# How make scatterplot in pandas readable

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've been playing with Titanic dataset and working through some visualisations in Pandas using this tutorial. https://www.kdnuggets.com/2023/02/5-pandas-plotting-functions-might-know.html

[image]

I have a visual of scatterplot having used this code.

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
```

I was confused by bootstrap plot result so went on to scatterplot.

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, figsize=(10,10), )
plt.show()
```

I can sort of interpret it but I'd like to put the various variables at top and bottom of every column. Is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 3, figsize=(20, 15))

sns.scatterplot(x = 'bedrooms', y = 'price', data = dataset, whis=1.5, ax=ax[0, 0])
sns.scatterplot(x = 'bathrooms', y = 'price', data = dataset, whis=1.5, ax=ax[0, 1])
```